# Why does a conda package need a setup.py file?

Tags: python, pip, conda, setup.py, conda-build

Why do I need a `setup.py` file which is commonly needed to build a python package when I instead want to build using conda? I.e. gradle also does not need mavens XML files to be present.

Comment: Have you searched for documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

Though conda uses different format (`meta.yml`) for registering dependencies, many conda packages are just a basic wrapper around `pip install`.

So lots of conda packages performs a build from `setup.py` and then pip installs.

Here's a example of `conda` being used as a wrapper around `pip install`.

https://github.com/conda-forge/requests-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml

Comment: Exactly. But what you are linking here is a conda-forge recipe i.e. a pip package which somehow was ported to conda. I am asking for native (conda first developed packages). Could I get rid of the additional files there?

Comment: Could you provide me any specific package for example?

Comment: I am in the process of creating a conda package myself (ideally without all the pip & setup.py overhead) as this means that certain metadata needs to be referenced > 1 time. Unfortunately, I do not have it sharable for now.